# Clone repo with submodules using nodegit

Tags: node.js, git, nodegit

What is the equivalent way of executing `git clone --recurse-submodules git@myrepo.git` with [NodeGit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit)?

I've found some [manual examples](https://gist.github.com/allomov/e9b7d4506c271a24e87d91371a323076) of how to do it but they're quite old and I'm hoping there's a native way to do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this with nodegit natively because it's not supported by the underlying library, `libgit2`: https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1233#issuecomment-809717805